# リンクの色が変化しない stylus

Tags: css

chromeの拡張機能であるStylusで

```
*{color:#000000 !important;}
{color:#1A0DAB ;}
```

でリンクの色が#1A0DABに変化しない。
（`*{color:#000000 !important;}`、`a:link {color:#1A0DAB !important;}`でgoogle検索結果のリンクの色が`#1A0DAB`に変化しない。）

Comment: 念のため確認ですが、作成したスタイルは「保存」していますか？

Answer (score 1):

すべてのリンクに適用したいなら、`a:any-link{color:#1A0DAB;}`のように、`:any-link`を試してみてください。